# Fatal error with FB.init: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token

Tags: php, facebook

I have added like button to my application page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'xxxxx', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<fb:like href="apps.facebook.com/myapp"></fb:like>
```

With first reaload every thing is ok. After 2-3 page reload I have this error:

```
Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token. thrown
```

What is wrong with this?
I h[ave searched in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Uncaught+OAuthException%3A+Error+validating+access+token.) but couldnot find any result. ([only one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155342/why-has-my-facebook-access-token-suddenly-stopped-working-oauthexception-error))

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I found this thread on the Facebook dev forum. A dude says you need to add your app's API key to the initialization. Like so:

```
FB.init({appId: 'xxxxx', api_key: 'yyyyy', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
```

However this did not solve my problem. Might help you though.